# Image Carousel Using these PHP Arguments In An Array

Tags: php, wordpress, image, carousel

I have been trying for a long time to create an image carousel with the code that is displaying below but i cant seem to figure it out. The current code displays all the images(in the array) in a list view; anyone have any insights as to how i would go about this?

```
        <?php

        $images = get_custom_field( 'project_pictures' );

if ( is_array( $images ) && ! empty( $images ) ){

    foreach( $images as $image ){
        $thumbnail_id = get_attachment_id_from_url( $image );
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id );
        echo "<a href=\"{$image}\"><img src=\"{$thumbnail}\"></a>";

    }

} elseif( ! empty( $images ) ){

    $thumbnail_id = get_attachment_id_from_url( $images );
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $thumbnail_id );
    echo "<a href=\"{$images}\"><img src=\"{$thumbnail}\"></a>";
    //------------------------------------------New code Here// 
}   
        ?>  
////carousel code

<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=" <?php echo "<a href=\"{$image}\"><img src=\"{$thumbnail}\"></a>";" ?> alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="echo "<a href=\"{$image}\"><img class=\"d-block w-100\" src=\"{$thumbnail}\" alt=\"Slide {$thumbnail_id}\"></a>";" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you meaning "displays all the images(in the array) in a list view"?... It is just one image below another?

Comment: Ya exactly. project_pictures can have up to 10 images added per each user. here is a link of what it looks like right now https://imgur.com/csl20G8

Comment: You code is right, it is doing what its suppose to do... I think you are missing the fact that a carousel needs the CSS and, maybe, JavaScript to work... What are you doing  on your css and JS? have you check the bootstrap carousel? it can help you to achieve https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: Yes i have. Im not to sure on how to output each pictures in the array in a carousel. https://imgur.com/3TGLlD2

Comment: You can basically wrap it on your foreach like: `echo "<a href=\"{$image}\"><img class=\"d-block w-100\" src=\"{$thumbnail}\" alt=\"Slide {$thumbnail_id}\"></a>";` ... Are you making your own carousel or are you using an exisitng library (like bootstrap) ?

Comment: I posted this in two different versions. Which one would be correct?  ( i posted above in the original as it is not looking clean in this comment box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping and printing it before the carousel structure... You need to loop it within the carousel structure... See:

```
   <?php
        // GET CAROUSEL IMAGES ARAY
        $images = get_custom_field( 'project_pictures' );
        //CHECK IF THERE IS IMAGES
        if ( !empty( $images ) ):
    ?>
        <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php
                //LOOP CAROUSEL IMAGES
                foreach( $images as $key => $image ):
                    $thumbnail_id = get_attachment_id_from_url( $image );
                    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id );
                ?>
                    <div 
                        class="carousel-item <?php 
                        //check if is the first carousel item to activate it
                        echo ($key==0)?'active':'';?>"
                    >
                        <a href="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                            <img 
                                class="d-block w-100" 
                                src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" 
                                alt="Slide <?php echo $thumbnail_id; ?>"
                            >
                        </a>
                    </div><!-- .carousel-item -->
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
        </div><!-- .carousel -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you are god! Thank you <3